# Check and display all Order items that have a SKU in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

having a problem with a custom script to show SKU's in Woocommerce > Admin > Orders screen. I can't seem to show to the sku

Trying

```
        switch ( $column )
    {
  case 'my_custom_column' :
  $the_sku = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku' )
```

then later I use something like this to display an error message (for myself) if the item doesn't have an SKU.

```
if(!empty($the_sku)) {
     echo "<a href=''><div class='order_div'>SKU is".$the_sku."</div></a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href=''><div class='order_div'>NO SKU</div></a>";
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It won't even echo the SKU (when it exists). So I'm a bit stuck. Ideally I'm trying to check whether each item in the order (an order may have several items attached) each has its own SKU.

If SKU's are not present an error is shown in the Orders column. Any help most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sku is not related to orders but to order items (Products) and an order can have many items, so you need to use something different.

The following code will get and check the order items to get the SKUs and if there is product that don't have it will display the missing SKUs count:

```
switch ( $column ) {
    case 'my_custom_column' :

        // Get the WC_Order instance object
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        $has_sku = false;
        $skus = [];
        $missing = 0;

        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
            $product = $item->get_product();

            if( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) {
                $has_sku = true;
                $skus[] = $sku;
            } else {
                $missing++;
            }
        }
```

Then later:

```
echo '<a href=""><div class="order_div">';

if ( $has_sku ) {
    echo __( "SKUs: %s") . ' ' . implode( ', ', $skus );
} else {
    echo __( "NO SKU" );
}

// Display missing SKUs count (optionally)
if( $missing > 0 ){
    echo ' <em>(' . $missing . ' missing)</em>';
}

echo '</div></a>';
```

It should work now.

Comment: you are so helpful. I now understand the complexity. Thanks for pointing out a solution and advising me how to get there. Your answer works great. I will meddle further, ideally I'd like to show a warning if in an order which has multiple items, one or more has a missing SKU. But I can take it from here I'm sure. I'll try. Thanks so so much.

Comment: @Callum I have just made an update with the missing Skus count, if it helps